# unable to install Botium CLI "npm install -g botium-cli" giving error message

Tags: node.js, testing, installation, chatbot

I tried to install BotiumCLI using command `npm install -g botium-cli` with NodeJS v12.19. During installation am receiving a error as mentioned in below.

Error am receiving during installation

```
npm ERR! prepareGitDep 1>
npm ERR! prepareGitDep > grpc@1.24.3 install C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\git-clone-9c4143df\node_modules\grpc
npm ERR! prepareGitDep > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
npm ERR! prepareGitDep
npm ERR! prepareGitDep [grpc] Success: "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\git-clone-9c4143df\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node" is installed via remote
npm ERR! prepareGitDep
npm ERR! prepareGitDep > core-js@2.6.11 postinstall C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\git-clone-9c4143df\node_modules\core-js
npm ERR! prepareGitDep > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
npm ERR! prepareGitDep
npm ERR! prepareGitDep Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!
npm ERR! prepareGitDep
npm ERR! prepareGitDep The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon:
npm ERR! prepareGitDep > https://opencollective.com/core-js
npm ERR! prepareGitDep > https://www.patreon.com/zloirock
npm ERR! prepareGitDep
npm ERR! prepareGitDep Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)
npm ERR! prepareGitDep
npm ERR! prepareGitDep
npm ERR! prepareGitDep > protobufjs@6.10.1 postinstall C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\git-clone-9c4143df\node_modules\protobufjs
npm ERR! prepareGitDep > node scripts/postinstall
npm ERR! prepareGitDep
npm ERR! prepareGitDep
npm ERR! prepareGitDep > actions-on-google-testing@0.4.0 prepare C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\git-clone-9c4143df
npm ERR! prepareGitDep > tsc && cp -r ./locales ./dist
npm ERR! prepareGitDep
npm ERR! prepareGitDep
npm ERR! prepareGitDep 2> npm WARN install Usage of the `--dev` option is deprecated. Use `--also=dev` instead.
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm WARN deprecated @types/winston@2.4.4: This is a stub types definition. winston provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.4: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm WARN deprecated flat@4.1.0: Fixed a prototype pollution security issue in 4.1.0, please upgrade to ^4.1.1 or ^5.0.1.
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm ERR! prepareGitDep node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download
npm ERR! prepareGitDep 'cp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
npm ERR! prepareGitDep operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm ERR! actions-on-google-testing@0.4.0 prepare: `tsc && cp -r ./locales ./dist`
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm ERR!
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm ERR! Failed at the actions-on-google-testing@0.4.0 prepare script.
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! prepareGitDep
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-11T14_10_45_170Z-debug.log
npm ERR! prepareGitDep
npm ERR! premature close

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-11T14_10_45_696Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Screenshots of error messages are hard to read, would you kindly edit your post with only the relevant text error messages?

Comment: try to install it with the git bash